# Why use the letter "k" in the function transformation formula $f(x - h) + k$?

Tags: functions, math-history

This is strictly a historical "why is it the letter k rather than say v for vertical" question -- is it the initial letter of something from a specific language? Is it arbitrary?

While we're at it, did "h" originally stand for "horizontal" or was it something else?

Comment: Probably because k follows h in alphabetical order

Comment: @Siminore at least if you ignore $i$ and $j$

Comment: I and j are historically used for integral indices. If you write $x+i $, many readers understand that $x $ is incremented by a positive integer.

Comment: This is a great theory (I'll buy i and j being skipped especially if they appear in the same text) but I'd really like a reference cite. Also, does that mean "h" is truly arbitrary and it sharing an initial letter with "horizontal" is an accident?

Comment: I recall this question being asked before (as I tried to research the answer).  I came up dry.  I can't remember enough about the duplicate question to link to it.

Comment: It is definitely sure that $h$ doesn't come from the initial letter of "horizontal".

Comment: Most probably because of the visual similarity between the two letters in their handwritten form, since *h* is to *x* what *k* is to *f*.

Comment: konstante is German for constant thus the k, maybe?

Comment: Actually i didn't knew what i'm going to say until 5 minutes ago. Try traducting vertical to the greek, you will got a word starting with the greek letter kappa ($\kappa$).

Comment: Cauchy used $h$ and $k$, with slightly different meaning but still associated with the domain and range of a real function respectively, in a proof about limits in his *Cours d'Analyse* in 1821 (see Jeff Miller's [Earliest Uses of Symbols of Calculus](http://jeff560.tripod.com/calculus.html), scroll down to "Delta and epsilon").

Answer (score 1):

These websites essentially say that $h$ and $k$ weren't used that often, and so they were just used because all the other letters were used up. There is also some probable relationship to the German word "konstant."
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20170911021602/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/57023.html)
http://ask.metafilter.com/260472/Why-is-the-center-of-a-circle-often-given-as-h-k

Answer (score 0):

1.There are a lot of words that can be used but we use letter "k". It just to show that the word represents a constant,or in German k*onstant*. So we can get an idea of use of k mostly for a constant.
2.Its is obvious that "h" doesn't stand for horizontal.It can be any thing but one can think it as a coincidence.